# How to make a socket connection to a microservice behind Zuul gateway?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, microservices, netflix-zuul

I have a Zuul gateway working with Eureka service discovery. There are multiple microservices built in Node.JS which work as they should through the Zuul gateway for all http requests. Each microservice is individually accessible for http requests. 
However, when I try to make a connection to any microservice that is accessible through direct http requests, it always fails with a CORS error

```
'http://backend_uri:4297/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N7qKIKV' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is it possible to connect a microservice through a Zuul gateway with socket.io? 
It's a simple socket.io connection method in the frontend

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4298');
```

If I change the port and connect to the service directly then the socket connection is made. But if I access the service from the Zuul gateway then its the error above.

Comment: I think you are looking for smth like this: https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/Push-Messaging as you can see it requires version 2.0 of zuul.

Comment: I did check it but all of that implementation is in Java and the micro-services in this project are in Node.JS. I haven't been able to make out if using Zuul-Push, the way its done in the Java examples on their library is even possible in Node.JS. Haven't  been able to find a wrapper or a module or anything